# Read file from resource folder always giving Inputstream is null in spring boot application

Tags: java, spring-boot

Always giving `Inputstream` is `null` in `spring boot` application for me.
 Below code for getting `inputstream object` and image is for my resource file location.
Why I am getting `inputstream object` is `null` I am not sure.

Is there any issue I am loading this file while running power mock test case

```
IDataSet dataSet;
InputStream is = ClassLoader.class.getResourceAsStream("/all/testdata.json");
if (dataScript.endsWith(".json")) {
   dataSet = new JsonDataSet(is);
}
```

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kQxug.png]

Answer (score 2):

Use the system classloader to access resources from the root:

```
ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream("/all/testdata.json");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use:

```
InputStream is = YourClass.class.getResourceAsStream("/all/testdata.json");
```

Java looks relative to YourClass for the given file path.

If you use:

```
InputStream is = YourClass.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("/all/testdata.json");
```

Java looks relative from the root of the class path.

So I assume that you are looking for the second option

Comment: Both options I am getting inputstream is null

Comment: Your files are in the test/resources directory. And you are trying to load this in test?

Comment: And can you show us how your code now looks with option 2?

Comment: IDataSet dataSet;
            InputStream is = BaseH2TorqueTestCase.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("/all/testdata.json");
            if (dataScript.endsWith(".json")) {
                dataSet = new JsonDataSet(is);
            } else {
                dataSet = new FlatXmlDataSetBuilder().build(is);
            }

Comment: An you run it with Maven, Gradle or in the IDE?

Comment: I am running in intelij IDE ,build tool is maven only

Comment: is there any issue i am loading this file while running power mock test cases